# Configuring a neo4j test container in Spring Boot with @Configuration file

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, testcontainers

I'm trying to run spock tests against a neo4j container using the TestContainers library. Previously, I used the test-harness library to run tests against an embedded neo4j database but the need to migrate to using TestContainers has come up. With test-harness I used a configuration file to include some necessary beans for callback functionality. Without these beans, some unit tests are failing.

**Previous test-harness method**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [
        Neo4jTestHarnessAutoConfiguration,
        Neo4jDriverAutoConfiguration,
        Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration,
        CustomNeo4jConfiguration
])
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = [
        Neo4jTestHarnessAutoConfiguration,
        Neo4jDriverAutoConfiguration,
        Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration
])
@Transactional
trait EmbeddedNeo4j {
    // Neo4j embedded database is created in Neo4jTestHarnessAutoConfiguration
}
```

**CustomNeo4jConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(value = {
        "data.neo4j.nodes",
        "data.neo4j.relationships",
        "data.neo4j.queryresults"
})
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("data.neo4j.repository")
@EnableNeo4jAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class CustomNeo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware(){
        return new CustomAuditorAwareImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeforeBindCallback neo4jCustomEntitiesCallback(AuditorAware<String> auditorAware) {
        return new CustomNeo4jEntitiesCallback(auditorAware);
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jConversions neo4jCustomConversions() {
        Set<GenericConverter> additionalConverters = Collections.singleton(new InstantStringConverter());
        return new Neo4jConversions(additionalConverters);
    }
}
```

The above method works fine. All tests run properly and all beans are created.

**TestContainers attempt**

```
@Testcontainers
@Transactional
trait EmbeddedNeo4j {

    @Shared
    static final Neo4jContainer<?> neo4jContainer = new Neo4jContainer<>("neo4j:4.3.9")
            .withReuse(true)

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        neo4jContainer.start()

        registry.add("spring.neo4j.uri", neo4jContainer::getBoltUrl)
        registry.add("spring.neo4j.authentication.username", () -> "neo4j")
        registry.add("spring.neo4j.authentication.password", neo4jContainer::getAdminPassword)
    }
}
```

With the above, all tests successfully run against the test container. However, any test that needs the functionality of the beans in the CustomNeo4jConfiguration fails.

**What I've tried**

I've attempted to use the same @ContextConfiguration annotations in various configurations, such as...

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [
        Neo4jDriverAutoConfiguration,
        Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration,
        CustomNeo4jConfiguration
])
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = [
        Neo4jDriverAutoConfiguration,
        Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration
])
@Transactional
trait EmbeddedNeo4j {
    TestContainer code here...
```

However, this fails with the following stack trace:

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'auditFieldRepository' defined in data.neo4j.repository.AuditFieldRepository defined in @EnableNeo4jRepositories declared on CustomNeo4jConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'neo4jTemplate' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:874)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 82 more
```

I've also attempted in various ways to create the missing beans, but that doesn't feel like the right path to take and that didn't produce any results.

What's the right way to use a @Configuration file with TestContainers?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret your mixture of Java and Scala code correctly, I would recommend the following approach, but *only* if you insist on not using `@SpringBootTest`.

Also: You are using the outdated `neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter` classes, they aren't needed for a while now in recent Spring Boot and also will potentially break SDN6+.

Please note: You should *never* import auto configuration classes and use them as `ContextConfiguration` at the same time. They are only meant to be imported via `@ImportAutoConfiguration`, but even that is redundant or overly complicated most of the time.

First of all, here's the pom so you get the proper dependencies:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>neowithapoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>neowithapoc</name>
    <description>neowithapoc</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Solution 1**

Here's a solution that goes into what you have there, with a trait - or in case of pure java - abstract test class:

```java
package com.example.neowithapoc;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.neo4j.Neo4jAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jLabsPlugin;

@TestConfiguration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({
    Neo4jAutoConfiguration.class,
    Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(considerNestedRepositories = true)
public abstract class EmbeddedNeo4jConfig {

    static final Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>("neo4j:4.4")
        .withLabsPlugins(Neo4jLabsPlugin.APOC)
        .withReuse(true);

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {

        neo4j.start();

        registry.add("spring.neo4j.uri", neo4j::getBoltUrl);
        registry.add("spring.neo4j.authentication.username", () -> "neo4j");
        registry.add("spring.neo4j.authentication.password", neo4j::getAdminPassword);
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```java
package com.example.neowithapoc;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jClient;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EmbeddedNeo4jConfig.class)
public class SomeTest extends EmbeddedNeo4jConfig {

    @Test
    void whatever(@Autowired Neo4jTemplate template, @Autowired Neo4jClient client) {
        assertThat(template).isNotNull();
        assertThat(client).isNotNull();

        String apoc = client
            .query("RETURN apoc.version() AS output")
            .fetchAs(String.class)
            .first().get();
        assertThat(apoc).startsWith("4.4");
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

I do prefer this way simpler and less complicated approach:

```java
package com.example.neowithapoc;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jClient;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.Neo4jTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jLabsPlugin;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)
public class SomeSpringBootTest {

    static final Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>("neo4j:4.4")
        .withLabsPlugins(Neo4jLabsPlugin.APOC)
        .withReuse(true);

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {

        neo4j.start();

        registry.add("spring.neo4j.uri", neo4j::getBoltUrl);
        registry.add("spring.neo4j.authentication.username", () -> "neo4j");
        registry.add("spring.neo4j.authentication.password", neo4j::getAdminPassword);
    }

    @Test
    void whatever(@Autowired Neo4jTemplate template, @Autowired Neo4jClient client) {
        assertThat(template).isNotNull();
        assertThat(client).isNotNull();

        String apoc = client
            .query("RETURN apoc.version() AS output")
            .fetchAs(String.class)
            .first().get();
        assertThat(apoc).startsWith("4.4");
    }
}
```

**Bonus questions custom conversions**

Given the following class:

```java
package com.example.neowithapoc;

public class SomeObject {
    private final String value;

    public SomeObject(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

It is not an entity and it needs some special treatment during conversions.

It can be converted back and forth like this:

```java
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.driver.Value;
import org.neo4j.driver.Values;
import org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter;

public class SomeObjectConverter implements GenericConverter {
    @Override public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Set.of(
            new ConvertiblePair(Value.class, SomeObject.class),
            new ConvertiblePair(SomeObject.class, Value.class)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {

        if (source == null) {
            return Value.class.isAssignableFrom(targetType.getType()) ? Values.NULL : null;
        } else if (source instanceof SomeObject someObject) {
            return Values.value(someObject.getValue());
        } else if (source instanceof Value value) {
            return new SomeObject(value.asString());
        } else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Configure it with a `@TestConfiguration` (or on your main config) like this

```java
@TestConfiguration
static class AdditionalBeans {

    @Bean
    SomeObjectConverter someObjectConverter() {
        return new SomeObjectConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    Neo4jConversions neo4jConversions(SomeObjectConverter someObjectConverter) {
        return new Neo4jConversions(List.of(someObjectConverter));
    }
}
```

In both cases this class is a static nested class of either `EmbeddedNeo4jConfig` and `SomeSpringBootTest`.

In the former you normally would just declare the bean method directly, but as I tried to recreate your "trait" as much as possible in Java and I do extend that class, this is not possible. Tests must not have their own `@Bean` methods.

After that, test like this

```java
@Node
static class ContainerNode {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    SomeObject someObject;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public SomeObject getSomeObject() {
        return someObject;
    }
}

@Test
void conversionsShouldWork(@Autowired Neo4jTemplate template) {

    var container = template.find(ContainerNode.class)
        .matching("CREATE (n:ContainerNode {someObject: 'Hello'}) RETURN n")
        .one();
    assertThat(container).map(ContainerNode::getSomeObject).map(SomeObject::getValue).hasValue("Hello");
}
```

will work just fine, also with the repository.

This test here will fail

```java
@Test
void conversionsShouldWork(@Autowired Neo4jClient client) {
    var anObject = client.query("RETURN 'whatever'").fetchAs(SomeObject.class).first();
    assertThat(anObject).map(SomeObject::getValue).hasValue("whatever");
}
```

but the Spring Data Neo4j fixed this in 6.3.3 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2594 and you would be able to manually add it to the client like this:

```java
@TestConfiguration
static class AdditionalBeans {

    @Bean
    SomeObjectConverter someObjectConverter() {
        return new SomeObjectConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    Neo4jConversions neo4jConversions(SomeObjectConverter someObjectConverter) {
        return new Neo4jConversions(List.of(someObjectConverter));
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jClient neo4jClient(
        Driver driver,
        DatabaseSelectionProvider databaseSelectionProvider,
        Neo4jConversions neo4jConversions) {

        return Neo4jClient.with(driver)
            .withDatabaseSelectionProvider(databaseSelectionProvider)
            .withNeo4jConversions(neo4jConversions)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Than this test will work just fine:

```java
@Test
void clientConversionsShouldWork(@Autowired Neo4jClient client) {
    var anObject = client.query("RETURN 'whatever'").fetchAs(SomeObject.class).first();
    assertThat(anObject).map(SomeObject::getValue).hasValue("whatever");
}
```

Comment: Something I neglected to mention the first time was that all test classes are annotated with SpringBootTest.


The problem I'm still facing is getting the CustomNeo4jConfiguration class to be picked up. Including it in the @ImportAutoConfiguration annotation from Solution 1 does not work.


I have all tests pass, except the ones that need the audit fields configured in that class.


What would be the proper way to use the configuration file?

Comment: To put it in simpler terms, how would I include a Neo4jConversions bean in my context configuration? Just adding it to the annotation is not working correctly.